# How to remove first and last character of a string in Rust?

Tags: string, rust

I'm wondering how I can remove the first and last character of a string in Rust.

Example:

Input:

`"Hello World"`

Output:

`"ello Worl"`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I got it, after trying, I'll post an answer

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use the `.chars()` iterator and ignore the first and last characters:

```
fn rem_first_and_last(value: &str) -> &str {
    let mut chars = value.chars();
    chars.next();
    chars.next_back();
    chars.as_str()
}
```

It returns an empty string for zero- or one-sized strings and it will handle multi-byte unicode characters correctly. See it working on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dc91aae858d26f39c12892ec40d6044d).

Comment: This is my favourite answer because it works with multi-byte characters and empty strings.

Comment: As always when playing with unicode, it is worth remembering the difference between characters and grapheme clusters. For example, there are cases where this will remove an accent on the last glyph or change a compound emoji, rather than removing the whole cluster. So while this gives what the OP asks for, it may not actually be what they want. (More a warning for the OP, than a criticism of this answer - properly handling grapheme clusters is _tricky_ and non-trivial)

Comment: @MichaelAnderson Absolutely! I never know how in-depth to go with unicode handling. For more complicated glyphs and emojis, swapping `.chars()` to [`.graphemes(true)`](https://unicode-rs.github.io/unicode-segmentation/unicode_segmentation/trait.UnicodeSegmentation.html#tymethod.graphemes) from the [unicode segmentation](https://crates.io/crates/unicode-segmentation) crate may be necessary.

Answer (score 25):

…or the trivial solution
*also works with Unicode characters:*

```
let mut s = "Hello World".to_string();
s.pop();      // remove last
if s.len() > 0 {
    s.remove(0);  // remove first
}
```

Comment: Worth noting that [remove](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.remove) is an `O(n)` operation.

Comment: @Sarkar Correct – but it doesn't result in a memory allocation.

Answer (score 23):

I did this by using string slices.

```rust
fn main() {
    let string: &str = "Hello World";
    let first_last_off: &str = &string[1..string.len() - 1];
    println!("{}", first_last_off);
}
```

I took all the characters in the string until the end of the string - 1.

Comment: What happens if the string is empty? will the program crash?

Comment: I could add an if statement:

`if string.is_empty() { "" }`

Comment: I think this would also work `&string[1..];`

Comment: Warning: this code will only work for ASCII characters, where 1 char = 1 byte. If your string starts/ends with a UTF-8 character represented by 2 or more bytes, the code will panic.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use split_at().

```
let msg = "Hello, world!";
let msg = msg.split_at(msg.len() - 1);
let msg = msg.0.split_at(1);
println!("{}", msg.1);

ello, world
```

`split_at()` returns the following: `(&str, &str)`.

Comment: You can bind to a tuple to discard the unused part: `let (msg, _) = msg.split_at(msg.len() - 1); let (_, msg) = msg.split_at(1)` But since this will panic for non-ASCII characters, I would more likely use kmdreko's answer in most cases.

Comment: I replaced hello with "Jeg æder blåbærsyltetøj!" (I'm eating blueberryjam in Danish).
and it gave "eg æder blåbærsyltetøj".

Comment: `J` and `!` are ASCII characters. Try `Я ем черничное варенье` or `블루 베리 잼 먹고 있어요` and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: I see. I thought you meant it was counting an UTF-8-character incorrectly and this could lead to a panick.