# Why does `rev().rev()` work but `rev().skip(1).rev()` does not?

Tags: rust

As title, in Rust, `.rev().rev()` works,  `.rev().skip(1)` works, but `.rev().skip(1).rev()` does not. The following is the demonstration:

```
// This compiles
fn main() {
    let s = "Hello!";
    println!("{}", &s.chars().rev().skip(1).collect::<String>());
}
```

```
// This compiles
fn main() {
    let s = "Hello!";
    println!("{}", &s.chars().rev().rev().collect::<String>());
}
```

```
// This *does not* compile
fn main() {
    let s = "Hello!";
    println!("{}", &s.chars().rev().skip(1).rev().collect::<String>());
}
```

The last one does not compile:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Chars<'_>: ExactSizeIterator` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:3:45
  |
3 |     println!("{}", &s.chars().rev().skip(1).rev().collect::<String>());
  |                                             ^^^ the trait `ExactSizeIterator` is not implemented for `Chars<'_>`
  |
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `ExactSizeIterator` for `Rev<Chars<'_>>`
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `DoubleEndedIterator` for `Skip<Rev<Chars<'_>>>`

error[E0599]: the method `collect` exists for struct `Rev<Skip<Rev<Chars<'_>>>>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:3:51
   |
3  |        println!("{}", &s.chars().rev().skip(1).rev().collect::<String>());
   |                                                      ^^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `Rev<Skip<Rev<Chars<'_>>>>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
   |
   = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `Skip<Rev<Chars<'_>>>: DoubleEndedIterator`
           which is required by `Rev<Skip<Rev<Chars<'_>>>>: Iterator`
           `Rev<Skip<Rev<Chars<'_>>>>: Iterator`
           which is required by `&mut Rev<Skip<Rev<Chars<'_>>>>: Iterator`
```

<sup>[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b18abcd28e15f1ad5cbee96d3a12491f)</sup>

Could someone explain why this is the case?

Comment: to be clear, even if this would compile two rev is a noop

Comment: If you're interested in simply removing the last character of a string, consider looking at the answers here for ideas: [How to remove first and last character of a string in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65976432/how-to-remove-first-and-last-character-of-a-string-in-rust)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`rev`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.rev) method returns a structure called `Rev<I>` where `I` is whatever iterator you called it on.

> For example, `my_str.chars()` gets you a `Chars` struct which is an iterator. Calling `.rev()` gets you `Rev<Chars>`.

`.rev()` requires that `I` be a [`DoubleEndedIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.DoubleEndedIterator.html) (which makes sense, reversing is done by just iterating from the back to the front).

The [`skip`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.skip) method returns a structure called `Skip<I>` where similarly, `I` is whatever iterator you called it on.

This is callable on any iterator (which makes sense).

**However**, `Skip<I>` only implements `DoubleEndedIterator` if `I` implements `DoubleEndedIterator` *and* [`ExactSizeIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.ExactSizeIterator.html).

That means, that we can only call `.rev` on a `Skip<I>` if `I: DoubleEndedIterator + ExactSizeIterator`.

One last piece before we look at what you've written: [`Chars`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Chars.html) implements `DoubleEndedIterator` **but not** `ExactSizeIterator` since characters are variable length when encoded in utf8.

Taking a look at this whole thing:

```rs
s
    .chars() // DoubleEndedIterator
    .rev()   // DoubleEndedIterator
    .skip()  // Doesn't implement DoubleEndedIterator because it doesn't implement ExactSizeIterator
    .rev()   // Err, we need DoubleEndedIterator here.
```

Comment: Thanks for including the brief explanation of _why_ `Chars` doesn't implement `ExactSizeIterator`.

Answer (score 19):

Calling [`.chars()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.chars) returns an [`Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) ([`Chars`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Chars.html)) which implements [`DoubleEndedIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.DoubleEndedIterator.html), which using [`.rev()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.rev) requires.

```rust
fn rev(self) -> Rev<Self>
where
    Self: DoubleEndedIterator
```

Then calling [`.skip()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.skip) produces a new [`Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) ([`Skip`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Skip.html)), which **only** implements [`DoubleEndedIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.DoubleEndedIterator.html) if the [`Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) (in this case [`Chars`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Chars.html)) implements both [`DoubleEndedIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.DoubleEndedIterator.html) and [`ExactSizeIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.ExactSizeIterator.html).

```rust
impl<I> DoubleEndedIterator for Skip<I>
where
    I: DoubleEndedIterator + ExactSizeIterator
```

However, [`Chars`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Chars.html) does not implement [`ExactSizeIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.ExactSizeIterator.html). So [`DoubleEndedIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.DoubleEndedIterator.html) is not implemented for [`Skip`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Skip.html). So now the requirement for calling [`.rev()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.rev) is no longer uphold for the second call.

Answer (score -3):

Two `rev()` is anyway a noop, `Iterator` are lazy so the second `rev()` cancel the first one unless the iterator is consumed between the two call.

To skip the last item of an iterator and then collect it in order, I will do:

```rust
use std::iter::{DoubleEndedIterator, FromIterator, Iterator};

fn collect_rev_nth_n_rev<I, C>(items: I, n: usize) -> C
where
    I: DoubleEndedIterator,
    C: FromIterator<<I as Iterator>::Item>,
{
    let mut iter = items.rev();
    iter.nth(n);
    iter.rev().collect()
}

fn main() {
    let result: String = collect_rev_nth_n_rev("Hello!".chars(), 0);
    assert_eq!("Hello", result);
}
```

`nth()` is often nicely optimized.